# How to pass model instance from table to modal popup?

Tags: c#, razor

I have this piece of code, which generates a table of records (name and info) and each row should have a edit button which opens a modal popup that allows to edit Info section of the record. 
1. HTML view

```
@model Właściwy.Models.BoardViewModel
...
@foreach (var p in Model.LoansNumerable)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>@p.Name</td>
                    <td>@p.Info</td>
                    <td><button 
onclick="javascript:openModal('ModalEdit')">Edit</button></td>
                </tr>
```

2. The same cshtml file but the code for modal popup for editing records in the table above

```
<div class="ModalEdit">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Loan", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <label>Edit info: </label>
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LoanElement.Info)<br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="button-
submit" formaction="~/Controller/Info/@Model.LoanElement"/>
                    }
                </div>
```

How do I pass information about record which I want to edit from table in 1st piece of code, to the modal, which will allow me to send chosen record from the table and edited part of the record in the modal, to the controller in order to place it into SQL database? Because "Controller/Info/@Model.LoanElement" part in the modal code only passes the edited part, the rest becomes nulls

Comment: using Javascript would be your best bet. Using razor won't work because that only executes on the server, before the page is being displayed. Javascript is how you manipulate the page once it's in use. You've made a start by using script to show the modal, you need script to fetch the data too (either transfer it from the table by pulling the contents out of the HTML, or maybe use ajax to fetch the relevant object by its ID from the server, esp. if there are more attributes than shown in the table).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should generate an ajax link in your html table, in order to load the form with a partial view. Something like this:

```
@foreach (var p in Model.LoansNumerable)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@p.Name</td>
        <td>@p.Info</td>
        <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @p.Id }, new AjaxOptions()
                {
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "idOfContainerInsideModal"
                })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

You should have an Edit action, rendering a partial view with the form.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = //get model from id
    return PartialView("Edit", model);
}
```

Then, your Edit view with a form to your model. I think you should use an AjaxForm, that submits the value, close the modal, and update the table after the data is submitted.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostEdit", new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "reload Page function",
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    }))
{
        <label>Edit info: </label>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LoanElement.Info)<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="button-submit"/>
}
```